# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree al momento de ejecutar ionic capacitor add android

Tags: android, nodejs, ionic, ionic-framework, capacitor

Estoy teniendo este error de dependencias el cual no he podido solucionar, ya he verificado incluso con varios comandos como no me han dado resultados.
Hice un app con Ionic usando Capacitor y quiero probarla en mi dispositivo, pero resulta que al momento de ingresar este comando `ionic capacitor add android` me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya utilice los siguientes comandos e igual no he tenido éxito como, `--force`, `--legacy-peer-deps`, `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, incluso intente actualizar capacitor y no pude `npm install @capacitor/android@latest`.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda .

Al igual vi los archivos que me menciona pero igual no he sabido como solucionarlo.

`# npm resolution error report`

2021-04-09T17:41:57.683Z

While resolving: bilder@0.0.1
Found: @capacitor/core@3.0.0-rc.0
node_modules/@capacitor/core
@capacitor/core@"^3.0.0-rc.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @capacitor/core@"~2.4.0" from @capacitor/android@2.4.7
node_modules/@capacitor/android
@capacitor/android@"2.4.7" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
"code": "ERESOLVE",
"current": {
"name": "@capacitor/core",
"version": "3.0.0-rc.0",
"whileInstalling": {
"name": "bilder",
"version": "0.0.1",
"path": "C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder"
},
"location": "node_modules/@capacitor/core",
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "@capacitor/core",
"spec": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder"
}
}
]
},
"edge": {
"type": "peer",
"name": "@capacitor/core",
"spec": "~2.4.0",
"error": "INVALID",
"from": {
"name": "@capacitor/android",
"version": "2.4.7",
"whileInstalling": {
"name": "bilder",
"version": "0.0.1",
"path": "C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder"
},
"location": "node_modules/@capacitor/android",
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "@capacitor/android",
"spec": "2.4.7",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder"
}
}
]
}
},
"peerConflict": null,
"strictPeerDeps": false,
"force": false
}

y este es el otro.

`0 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '--save',
0 verbose cli   '@capacitor/android@2.4.7'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.6.3
2 info using node@v15.7.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Caruso.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 11ms
19 verbose npm-session de7bf525534b277c
20 timing npm:load Completed in 19ms
21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
22 timing idealTree:init Completed in 628ms
23 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
24 silly idealTree buildDeps
25 silly fetch manifest @capacitor/android@2.4.7
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
27 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor%2fandroid 814ms (from cache)
28 silly fetch manifest @capacitor/core@^3.0.0-rc.0
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@capacitor%2fcore 147ms (from cache)
30 silly fetch manifest @capacitor/core@~2.4.0
31 timing idealTree Completed in 1605ms
32 timing command:install Completed in 1610ms
33 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
33 verbose stack     at Arborist.[failPeerConflict] (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1157:25)
33 verbose stack     at Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1134:34)
33 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:838:11)
33 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:209:7)
33 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
33 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:131:5)
33 verbose stack     at async Install.install (C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:120:5)
34 verbose cwd C:\Users\Caruso\Desktop\Ionic\09-bilder
35 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
36 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "@capacitor/android@2.4.7"
37 verbose node v15.7.0
38 verbose npm  v7.6.3
39 error code ERESOLVE
40 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
41 error
42 error While resolving: bilder@0.0.1
42 error Found: @capacitor/core@3.0.0-rc.0
42 error node_modules/@capacitor/core
42 error   @capacitor/core@"^3.0.0-rc.0" from the root project
42 error
42 error Could not resolve dependency:
42 error peer @capacitor/core@"~2.4.0" from @capacitor/android@2.4.7
42 error node_modules/@capacitor/android
42 error   @capacitor/android@"2.4.7" from the root project
42 error
42 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
42 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
42 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
42 error
42 error See C:\Users\Caruso\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
43 verbose exit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione compañeros, tuve que realizar un downgradem, al capacitor 2.4.7
Y eso soluciona el problema.
Gracias